# To "head" or NOT to "head"?

Tags: c, pointers, data-structures

I have a "pointer" which keeps incrementing and I need to return the "head" of the pointer finally. I am in a dilemma to use either "pointer[0]" or have another variable called "head" and initialize it and return at the end. The former I feel makes the code looks soiled and later costs little memory. Any clean suggestion?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code to make the question clearer.

Comment: use a temp variable and store address by reference. please add more detail its bit confusing statement above.

Comment: pseudo code
 char *string, *temp;
   temp= string;
   process string{
    string++.... }
   return (string[0])? or return temp? which is better?

Comment: if you're doing `string++`, you'll find that `string[0]` is _not_ the same as `temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will always need two variables:

```
Foo *head = getSomeList();
Foo *tail = head;
while (tail->isValid())
  ++tail;
// You have head and tail here
```

You cannot really implement it much differently because `tail[0] != head` (unless the list is empty).

*Showing the code and telling us what exactly you try to achieve might lead to better answers.*